# Show server output when running request specs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I use RSpec for integration tests. Unfortunately when running those request specs I often miss important errors as I don't directly see the output of the test web server. Is there a way to get this stuff on the console, too?

Answer (score 1):

If you mean **server logs** it should be something like this:

```
if rails_env = ENV['RAILS_ENV']
  require 'logger'
  logger = Logger.new(STDOUT)
  ActiveRecord::Base.logger = logger
  ActiveResource::Base.logger = logger
  Rails.logger = logger
end
```

Not sure about **server output**.

Comment: Thanks for the help. What do I get from `rails_env = ENV['RAILS_ENV']`? Did you really mean a variable assignment in that if clause?

Answer (score 1):

The output of the server during testing goes to `log/test.log` in your rails app directory. You can view it with

```
$ cat log/test.log
```

or, if you want something of a real time view,

```
$ watch -c -n 1 tail -40 log/test.log
```